# Python3 Manage.py Runserver Hangs when Running Through Git Bash

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, git-bash

I am a total python/git bash noob and new to this. Whenever I run command

```
$ python3 manage.py runserver
```

it seems to run it but hangs. I don't' get any output. How can I fix it or troubleshoot it?

My directory in which `manage.py` is located:

```
/c/python34/pythonprograms/superlists
```

Steps I have done:

1. `django-admin.py startproject superlists`
2. get into the `superlists` directory
3. `python3 manage.py runserver`
4. it runs however then it hangs and blinks. I get not output.

If anybody has some suggestions, can you please help me out with some simply-explained steps? Not sure how to get output on this one or how to make it work...all my environment variables seem to be good. I have environment variables setup in my settings for python, python (scripts folder), python (geckodriver).

Thank you,
Roman

Comment: You get no output at all?  Not even a message like "Starting development server ..." ?

Comment: Have you tried python3 django-admin.py runserver?